# Deleting specific line in file using batch script

Tags: file, batch-file

I found out that my batch script is not working properly. I wanted to write a function which deletes specific line in a file, this is my code:

```
:unmark
    type %MARKPATH% | findstr /B /V %1 > %MARKPATH_COPY%
GOTO:EOF
```

Yes, it works, but it writes new content (without specific lines) in a new file. But instead of it, I want to overwrite an existing file. Like that:

```
:unmark
    type %MARKPATH% | findstr /B /V %1 > %MARKPATH%
GOTO:EOF
```

But it's not working, file is empty after code execution. Can you help me figure out what is a problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

This style should work:

```
@echo off
set "MARKPATH=%userprofile%\desktop\input.txt"
set "MARKPATH_COPY=%userprofile%\desktop\searchfile.txt"

findstr /B /V "%~1" <"%markpath%" > "%MARKPATH_COPY%"
move /y "%MARKPATH_COPY%" "%markpath%" >nul
```

Comment: Great solution, but what does >nul do? EDIT: I just check it out, and it does not work properly. It writes lines if it contains string provided in findstr. Not delete it.

Comment: The >nul hides the message that `MOVE` prints to keep the screen clear.  The findstr command uses the same switches as your example.  Yours must be wrong too then. :D

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution to my problem (maybe not practical, but it worked)

```
:unmark
    set LASTPATH=%CD%
    cd %MARKPATH%
    type %MARKFILE% | findstr /B /V %1 > %MARKFILECOPY%
    del %MARKFILE%
    ren %MARKFILECOPY% %MARKFILE%
    cd %LASTPATH%
GOTO:EOF
```